# Check if Windows Installer 3.1 or higher is installed?

Tags: windows, registry, windows-installer, bootstrapper, dotnetinstaller

How can I check if Windows Installer version 4.5 is installed on target machine using registry.

I need to use this info in my installer bootstrapper and quit installation if WI 4.5 is not already installed.

I've checked HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\InstallerLocation
but no information about its version.

Please advice.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the MSI team themselves:

[How do detect the MSI version on the computer?](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windows_installer_team/archive/2005/09/09/458528.aspx)

[Windows Installer 3.1 Version Confusion](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windows_installer_team/archive/2005/08/05/448386.aspx)

From Stefan Krueger ( Windows Installer MVP )

[MSI Version Matrix](http://www.installsite.org/pages/en/msifaq/a/1001.htm)

Comment: Thanks! I need to add this condition in dotNetINstaller bootstrapper. So i need some way to check registry. I'm not sure how can I check file version from within dotNetInstaller file. Please advice.

Comment: MSI.dll is the only way to check.  I haven't used dotNetInstaller much but I'm fairly certain it'll be able to check DLL versions for you.

Comment: I am still looking to achieve this using dotnetinstaller. If it does not support this feature, then your solution is the only way to go. Anyways thanks so much for your time and suggestion.

Comment: The author of dotnetinstaller is active on this site and the WiX-Users mailing list.  I'm sure he'll be able to help you with the details and/or implement the capability if needed.